# Creating a program to file criminal cases and then view them, with new case being allowed to add

Tags: java, arrays, loops, save

I am a creating a program for taking input of criminal cases that have contents like Name, Crime, Date of Crime, etc... I want to create a program where, after taking input from user (i.e., details of the crime) it gets stored and when the user chooses to view cases, the new case that is filed, is also added to it. And this will be looped, i.e., if the user wants to input case again, he/she may do so, and the new case taken, will be added to already existing cases, including the case filed earlier.

I need an idea! I need an idea as to how can this be done! What shall I use? Will arrays help?

Comment: Where is the question? or do you want us to create the code for you? Rather read through [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: [Java Collections Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Comment: I need an idea! I need an idea as to how can this be done! What shall I use? Will arrays help?

Comment: oh and I realized I forgot to add the question to it! Extremely sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet is a very **basic** example of how something like this could be designed - it should give you a basic idea of how it could be expanded, to add more details to the cases or maybe add some other methods such as only viewing a specific case carrying a certain name or deleting a case which has been added.

Adding verification to the user input or storing the date in an Object which is better suited to it such as `java.time` might be first steps.

The `java.util.ArrayList` is likely the best choice for storing cases.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CriminalCase {

    //properties & getters
    private String name;
    public String getName(){return name;}
    private String date;
    public String getDate(){return date;}

    //constructor
    public CriminalCase(String name, String date){
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //this ArrayList will be used to store the cases
        ArrayList<CriminalCase> cases = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean quit = false;    

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!quit) {

            System.out.println("To view current cases enter v\nto add a case enter a\nto quit enter q");
            String input = s.nextLine();

            switch(input){
                case ("v"): {
                    System.out.println("The following cases exist:");
                    for (CriminalCase c : cases)
                         System.out.println("Name: " + c.getName() + " Date: " + c.getDate());
                    break;
                }
                case("a"):{
                    System.out.println("Enter a name:");
                    String name = s.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter a date (e.g. 17.09.2015)");
                    String date = s.nextLine();

                    cases.add(new CriminalCase(name,date));
                    break;
                }
                case("q"):{
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                }
                /*
                case("d"):{
                    //method to delete a case
                }

                 */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CriminalCase {




    private String batput;
    public String getBatput(){return batput;}


    public CriminalCase(String batput){
        this.batput = batput;

    }

private static class robin
{
   String Batman()
{
Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter name.");
String a=s.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Date of birth.");
String b=s.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Sex.");
String c=s.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Crime Committed.");
String d=s.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Date of Crime Committed.");
String e=s.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Victim.");
String f=s.nextLine();
System.out.println();
String g=""+"\n"+""+"Name:- "+a +"\nDOB:- "+b +"\nSex:- "+c +"\nCrime Committed:- "+d +"\nDate of Crime Committed:- "+e +"\nVictim:- "+f; 
return g;
}
}



    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList<CriminalCase> cases = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean quit = false;    

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

         robin j=new robin();  


        while (!quit) {

            System.out.println("To view current cases enter v\nto add a case enter a\nto quit enter q");
            String input = s.nextLine();

            switch(input){
                case ("v"): {
                    System.out.println("The following cases exist:");
                    for (CriminalCase c : cases)
                         System.out.println(c.getBatput());
                    break;
                }
                case("a"):{
                    String batput=j.Batman();

                    cases.add(new CriminalCase(batput));
                    break;
                }
                case("q"):{
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

}